# Does stackoverflow block user's short Profile view(when you hover over pic) for low reputation users?

Tags: discussion, profile-picture

Does stackoverflow block user's short Profile view(when you hover over pic) for low reputation users?

I experienced it many times.

For example [**Refer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=108852&tab=reputation&filter=all).

The user say : **[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1788/matt-brewer)** has profile info filled. Still on hovering his icon on **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=108852&tab=reputation&filter=all)** page, I don't get his Profile summary info.

May I know why is this? I mean logic behind it?

If you are not aware of Short profile view, please check :

[image: short profile]

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got it exactly the wrong way around.

The user card (which is what you are describing) is part of the [established user privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user), earned at 1,000 rep.

Comment: I didnt notice that as its not given here for user with 1000 rep. points(http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). Sorry about that.